# QuickSort in C++, having trouble

Tags: c++, quicksort

I'm trying to write this algorithm for C++, but when I try to run it, nothing comes up. I have looked at everything in terms of what is wrong, but I can't find it. I haven't programmed in a year, so I'm getting back into things. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void quickSort(int A[], int p, int r);
int partition(int A[], int p, int r);

int main(void)
{
    int elements = 8; 
    int number[8] = { 2, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4 };

    int first = 0;
    int last = elements - 1;

    quickSort(number, first, last);

    cout << "Sorted elements: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        cout << number[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;

}

void quickSort(int A[], int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
        int q= 0;
        q = partition(A, p, r);
        quickSort(A, p, q - 1);
        quickSort(A, q + 1, r);
    }
}

int partition(int A[], int p, int r)
{
    int temp;

    int x = A[r];
    int i = p - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < r - 1; j++)
    {
        if (A[j] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            temp = A[j];
            A[j] = A[i];
            A[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    temp = A[r];
    A[r] = A[i + 1];
    A[i + 1] = temp;

    return (i+1);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `quickSort(number, first, last);` from `main`, is it still the case that nothing comes up? If so then the problem isn't with your code, it's that you are running your program incorrectly.

Comment: If I remove that, the elements come up unsorted.

Comment: You've a run-time problem which ends up the execution, it seems somewhere is invoking an _undefined behavior_.

Comment: OK so it's likely crashing in your quicksort code somewhere. Time to use a debugger.

Comment: `int q = 0; q = partition(...);` why not just write `int q = partition(...);`

Comment: Okay, something comes up, but it's just a never-ending random numbers going down the screen. Also, it says "QuickSort.exe has stopped working."

Comment: Time to walk thru execution with the debugger. Hit `F11` to start the program and break when the program reaches main

Comment: Seems like you are corrupting the stack, which is likely an out of bounds access on your array. Like I said, use a debugger. Or just add some print statments to check your use of the array.

Comment: Incidentally, how are those variable names working out for you a year later? You know, 'p' and 'r'?

Comment: Kfsone, I will fix it later. I know what they stand for now, but I will fix that. Thank you.

Comment: Now it says, fatal error LNK1168: cannot open C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\QuickSort\Debug\QuickSort.exe for writing even though I didn't do anything major to change my program. The joy of starting up programming again.

Comment: That means there is a copy of the program running already. Pressing `F11` is an alternative to other ways of launching the program, it launches it in debug mode with the debugger attached and pauses (breaks) when execution reaches main, for you.

Comment: (F11 is a short cut for Debug -> Step Into)

Comment: Also, you can clear the code up for yourself a little by using `#include <algorithm>` and `std::swap(A[j], A[i]);` instead of using `temp = A[j]; A[j] = A[i]; A[i] = temp;`, in partition (you should be able to remove temp entirely)

Comment: Thanks kfsone, you have a been a huge help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Loop condition inside the partition function should be :

```
for (int j = p; j <= r-1; j++)
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I have quickly tested your program and for this input this version gives me the correct output:

```
int partition(int A[], int p, int r)
{
    int temp;

    int x = A[r];
    int i = p - 1;
    for (int j = p; j < r; j++)
    {
        if (A[j] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            temp = A[j];
            A[j] = A[i];
            A[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    temp = A[r];
    A[r] = A[i + 1];
    A[i + 1] = temp;

    return (i+1);
}
```

The change is in the loop limits.

Answer (score 1):

You're code stucks in an infinite recursion and consumes memory until invokes *undefined behavior*. Therefor it may stops execution and prints nothing.

Your `partition` function has serious problems, while I can not find out your logic, you should use a debugger to trap the problem. Check your `i` and `j` variables. For example this quick fix made some output which is correct:

```
for (int j = i+1; j < r ; j++)
             ^^^      ^
```

Output:

> Sorted elements: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

I'm not sure it will work for any size of data or not. [Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b656aadffd984c73).